# How to do AWS Signature Version 4 from a local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to test some Node.js code from my local machine for use in an AWS Lambda function. This involves signing a request with Signature Version 4.

I've signed in with my access key using AWS CLI but when I try to make a request using the following code I get this error at `signer.addAuthorization`. What step am I missing? It works fine from a Lambda function.

**Code:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const creds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
...
var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, 'es');
signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type undefined
    at new Hmac
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of EnvironmentCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EnvironmentCredentials.html),

> By default, this class will look for the matching environment variables prefixed by a given envPrefix

Therefore you need to set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` environment variables before invoking your code.

In AWS Lambda environment, these environment variables are already set, that's why it is working.